# How to get un-encrypted FTP login passwords from WinSCP export file?

Tags: passwords, ftp, winscp

I can't remember my FTP login passwords. But my FTP login passwords **saved** in WinSCP application. How I show my saved passwords? *(I have exported passwords as **WinSCP.ini** but I can't see the passwords. Because they are **encrypted**.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting WinSCP FAQ [Can I recover password stored in WinSCP session?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_password):

One way is to recover your password is enabling a password logging in preferences. See [*Log passwords and other sensitive information*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_logging) preference option. Then inspect the session log file to find the stored password.

```
. 2017-06-13 07:41:11.313 ---------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-06-13 07:41:11.313 WinSCP Version 5.15.1 (Build 9407) (OS 10.0.17763 - Windows 10)
. 2017-06-13 07:41:11.313 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2017-06-13 07:41:11.313 Log level: Normal, Logging passwords
...
. 2017-06-13 07:41:11.313 ---------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-06-13 07:41:11.313 Session name: My server (Site)
. 2017-06-13 07:41:11.313 Host name: example.com (Port: 22)
. 2017-06-13 07:41:11.313 User name: martin (Password: mypassword, Key file: No)
```

You can also abuse a [Generate Session URL/Code](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl) function to retrieve the saved password. Note that special symbols in the password may get escaped. You are most likely to see the password intact in the [.NET assembly code](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code), where only double-quotes are escaped (in all supported languages).

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!